# Mocking DateTime

Tags: c#, mocking

```
public void DoSomethingAccordingToYear()
{
    if(DateTime.Now.Year < 2010)
        DoSomething();
    else
        DoSomethingElse();
}
```

I want to test this method.
How can I mock DateTime **without changing my code and without using interfaces**?

Comment: change the time on your pc?

Comment: Neither of those options allow you to run tests automatically, please don't do that!

Comment: Also @TejashwiKalpTaru the `DateTime` object is immutable, you can't change it.

Comment: I would use different signature for testing/debuging [like this](http://rextester.com/XXZI58594)

Comment: You can also try using the virtual time from package Install-Package VirtualTime

Answer (score 4):

One common way to do this is to pass in a component that gets the date. For example:

```
public interface IDateTimeNowProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}

public class DateTimeNowProvider : IDateTimeNowProvider
{
    public DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;
}
```

Now you can inject a `IDateTimeNowProvider` into your object and mock that instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the definition of your method it would be simple:

```
public void DoSomethingAccordingToYear(DateTime testDate)
{
    if(testDate.Year < 2010)
        DoSomething();
    else
        DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
// production
DoSomethingAccordingToYear(DateTime.Now);

// test
DoSomethingAccordingToYear(new DateTime(2009,1,1));
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to change the way you call the method, you could also implement it like this:

```
public void DoSomethingAccordingToYear(DateTime? testDate = null)
{
    testDate = testDate ?? DateTime.Now;

    if (testDate.Year < 2010)
        DoSomething();
    else
        DoSomethingElse();
}
```

If you would call it without a parameter then it would use `DateTime.Now` but you can still pass a parameter for testing.